# How to send credit card form data to a finance companies by using their node app

Tags: html, node.js, firebase

Html (unnecessary details removed) will publish at firebase, and php is not working.

```
<form id="kkDetay"  name="kkCek" method="post">
       <input type="text" id="name-on-card" placeholder="Name Surname">
       <input type="text" id="card-number" placeholder="Card Number">
       <input type="text" id="card-exp-month" placeholder="Month">
       <input type="text" id="card-exp-year" placeholder="Year">
       <input type="text" id="card-cvc" placeholder="Cvc">
       <button  id="subm2" type="submit">Pay Now</button>
 </form>
```

Company https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-node and company node sample: in senddata.js (below)

```
var Iyzipay = require('iyzipay');
var iyzipay = new Iyzipay({
             apiKey: 'sandbox-PZ8jicWrEeE1rt1O75FTOegr5lsW3xxx',
             secretKey: 'sandbox-2Q6aaP1FK3HFrXkTsHfftxfiudFMfxxx',
             uri: 'https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com'
 });
var request = {
            locale: Iyzipay.LOCALE.TR,
            conversationId: '123456789',
            price: '1',
            paidPrice: '1.2',
            currency: Iyzipay.CURRENCY.TRY,
            installment: '1',.........................
            .....................................
            datas to send (full list at above link)
            }
    iyzipay.payment.create(request, function (err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);
        done();
    });
```

Now, when I use at Command prompt>  node senddata.js its working sending dummy datas.

How to connect and send form data to this senddata.js and run it at firebase server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run your own server-side code on Firebase.

To use that Node code that you gave as an example you would have to write a Node server, e.g. using Express, Hapi, Restify, LoopBack or some other framework, run it on some server, listen to requests and process them using the example code that you showed.

You HTML from would need to send the data to your Node server.

Keep in mind that you have to use HTTPS connection for that. Never send sensitive data such as names or credit card numbers unencrypted. I would not advise you do to it if you don't know what you're doing.

You may have a better luck integrating Stripe with Firebase because there are tutorials online. Also it's better to use a credit card service lie Stripe even if you're doing your own backend because with Stripe you don't actually process the credit card numbers yourself so there are less legal implications.

Comment: Hello @rsp, Thank you for the info. Unfortunately Stripe is not local for me. I saw this tutorial that works good. but I need a local service working with TRY, beside. There is same at Iyzipay (kk page at service side with their own window) https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/odeme-formu/odeme-formu-baslatma just the problem how to start this html code. at Firebase. (Btw, Happy new year :)

Comment: finally I found out the solution moving my project to gcloud appengine, instead firebase. Even I can access my firebase database same way at appengine.. Thank you for valuable information.